# Using Boost.Spirit.Lex and stream iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-spirit

I want use Boost.Spirit.Lex to lex a binary file; for this purpose I wrote the following program (here is an extract):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_multi_pass.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace lex = spirit::lex;

#define X 1
#define Y 2
#define Z 3

template<typename L>
class word_count_tokens : public lex::lexer<L>
{
    public:
        word_count_tokens () {
            this->self.add
                ("[^ \t\n]+", X)
                ("\n", Y)
                (".", Z);
        }
};

class counter
{
    public:
        typedef bool result_type;

        template<typename T>
        bool operator () (const T &t, size_t &c, size_t &w, size_t &l) const {
            switch (t.id ()) {
               case X:
                   ++w; c += t.value ().size ();
                    break;
               case Y:
                   ++l; ++c;
                    break;
                case Z:
                    ++c;
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream ifs (argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    auto first = spirit::make_default_multi_pass (std::istream_iterator<char> (ifs));
    auto last = spirit::make_default_multi_pass (std::istream_iterator<char> ());
    size_t w, c, l;
    word_count_tokens<lex::lexertl::lexer<>> word_count_functor;

    w = c = l = 0;

    bool r = lex::tokenize (first, last, word_count_functor, boost::bind (counter (), _1, boost::ref (c), boost::ref (w), boost::ref (l)));

    ifs.close ();

    if (r) {
        std::cout << l << ", " << w << ", " << c << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The build returns the following error:

```
lexer.hpp:390:46: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const char *' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type
```

Now, the error is due to definition of *concrete* lexer, `lex::lexer<>`; in fact its first parameter is defaulted to `const char *`. I obtain the same error also if I use `spirit::istream_iterator` or `spirit::make_default_multi_pass (.....)`.
But if I specify the correct template parameters of `lex::lexer<>` I obtain a plethora of errors!

Solutions?

**Update**

I have putted all source file; it's the word_counter site's example.

Comment: Of course, the exact types of `first` and `last` do matter. A lot.

Comment: I've fixed the code of your modified question. I fyou post a new question, I'll explain the fixes.

Comment: My problem was very simple, excuse me if my English was not very clear! :-( Now, if I want use something like the example at [Boost.Spirit.Lex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/lex/word_count_functor.cpp) but with `istream_iterator` instead `const char *`, the example doesn't compile reporting the specified error. In my update I put my actual code.

Comment: I have seen your update. I meant for you to post a new question, since your updated question would invalidate existing answers. Nevermind, I've just [posted a new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23757839/85371) then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since the question was changed, here's a new answer, addressing some points with the complete code sample.

1. Firstly, you need to use a custom token type. I.e.

   ```
   word_count_tokens<lex::lexertl::lexer<lex::lexertl::token<boost::spirit::istream_iterator>>> word_count_functor;
   // instead of:
   // word_count_tokens<lex::lexertl::lexer<>> word_count_functor;
   ```

   Obviously, it's customary to typedef `lex::lexertl::token<boost::spirit::istream_iterator>`
2. You need to use `min_token_id` instead of token IDs 1,2,3. Also, make it an enum for ease of maintenance:

   ```
   enum token_ids {
       X = lex::min_token_id + 1,
       Y,
       Z,
   };
   ```
3. You can no longer just use `.size()` on the default token `value()` since the iterator range is not RandomAccessRange anymore. Instead, employ `boost::distance()` which is specialized for `iterator_range`:

   ```
           ++w; c += boost::distance(t.value()); // t.value ().size ();
   ```

Combining these fixes: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2228051e17f6fbc)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace lex    = spirit::lex;

enum token_ids {
    X = lex::min_token_id + 1,
    Y,
    Z,
};

template<typename L>
class word_count_tokens : public lex::lexer<L>
{
    public:
        word_count_tokens () {
            this->self.add
                ("[^ \t\n]+", X)
                ("\n"       , Y)
                ("."        , Z);
        }
};

struct counter
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    template<typename T>
    bool operator () (const T &t, size_t &c, size_t &w, size_t &l) const {
        switch (t.id ()) {
            case X:
                ++w; c += boost::distance(t.value()); // t.value ().size ();
                break;
            case Y:
                ++l; ++c;
                break;
            case Z:
                ++c;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream ifs (argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    ifs >> std::noskipws;
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator first(ifs), last;
    word_count_tokens<lex::lexertl::lexer<lex::lexertl::token<boost::spirit::istream_iterator>>> word_count_functor;

    size_t w = 0, c = 0, l = 0;
    bool r = lex::tokenize (first, last, word_count_functor, 
            boost::bind (counter (), _1, boost::ref (c), boost::ref (w), boost::ref (l)));

    ifs.close ();

    if (r) {
        std::cout << l << ", " << w << ", " << c << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When run on itself, prints

```
65, 183, 1665
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks! This was my expected response! :-) But ... the Boost docs are not very explanatory ... That is, about defining token type was clear, but about min_token_id no! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem is not shown. You don't show `first` or `last` and I have a feeling you might have temporaries there.

Here's a sample I came up with to verify, perhaps you can see what it is you're doing ---wrong--- differently :)

- **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23617d7029d98560)** (memory mapped an byte-vector, via `const char*`)
- **[And this alternative](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/595c391789fc1db5)** (using `spirit::istream_iterator`)

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#ifdef MEMORY_MAPPED
#   include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#endif

namespace /*anon*/
{
    namespace qi =boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace lex=boost::spirit::lex;

    template <typename Lexer>
        struct mylexer_t : lex::lexer<Lexer>
    {
        mylexer_t()
        {
            fileheader = "hello";

            this->self = fileheader
                | space [ lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore ];
        }

        lex::token_def<lex::omit>
            fileheader, space;
    };

    template <typename Iterator> struct my_grammar_t
        : public qi::grammar<Iterator>
    {
        template <typename TokenDef>
            my_grammar_t(TokenDef const& tok) 
                : my_grammar_t::base_type(header)
        {
            header = tok.fileheader;
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(header);
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator> header;
    };
}

namespace /* */ {

    std::string safechar(char ch) {
        switch (ch) {
            case '\t': return "\\t"; break;
            case '\0': return "\\0"; break;
            case '\r': return "\\r"; break;
            case '\n': return "\\n"; break;
        }
        return std::string(1, ch); 
    }

    template <typename It>
        std::string showtoken(const boost::iterator_range<It>& range)
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << '[';
            std::transform(range.begin(), range.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss), safechar);
            oss << ']';
            return oss.str();
        }
}

bool parsefile(const std::string& spec)
{
#ifdef MEMORY_MAPPED
    typedef char const* It;
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mmap(spec.c_str(), boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readonly);
    char const *first = mmap.const_data();
    char const *last = first + mmap.size();
#else
    typedef char const* It;
    std::ifstream in(spec.c_str());
    in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    std::string v(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in.rdbuf()), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    It first = &v[0];
    It last = first+v.size();
#endif

    typedef lex::lexertl::token<It  /*, boost::mpl::vector<char, unsigned int, std::string> */> token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    typedef mylexer_t<lexer_type>::iterator_type iterator_type;
    try
    {
        static mylexer_t<lexer_type> mylexer;
        static my_grammar_t<iterator_type> parser(mylexer);

        auto iter = mylexer.begin(first, last);
        auto end  = mylexer.end();

        bool r = qi::parse(iter, end, parser);

        r = r && (iter == end);

        if (!r)
            std::cerr << spec << ": parsing failed at: \"" << std::string(first, last) << "\"\n";
        return r;
    }
    catch (const qi::expectation_failure<iterator_type>& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "FIXME: expected " << e.what_ << ", got '";
        for (auto it=e.first; it!=e.last; it++)
            std::cerr << showtoken(it->value());
        std::cerr << "'" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    if (parsefile("input.bin"))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

For the variant:

```
typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
std::ifstream in(spec.c_str());
in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

It first(in), last;
```

Comment: Your response was useful to understand that tokenize(...) cannot be used with other iterators instead of 'const char *'; it's correct? I must use actor_lexer to use custom iterators?

Comment: `actor_lexer` enabled the use of semantic actions (and state, IIRC) in the lexer. That's unrelated AFAICS. I did show the use of **[`boost::istream_iterator` in the alternative](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/595c391789fc1db5)**, so yes you can. If you have a modified version of this SSCCE that shows a problem you are stuck with, you might want to post _that_ as a question. **Edit** I see you've updated the question (...) 7 hours after my answer. I'll have a look at your modified question later